# Extract zipx format in ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, software-center

I compressed my folder using Windows7 and it compressed to `zipx` format. How can I extract it in ubuntu 12.04 because it encountered error while extracting. When I google for it I came across this 'http://www.westernwillow.com/cms/blog/franco/open-zipx-file-linux-ubuntu-or-mac-anything-other-windows-7' but it also gives me unsupprted error while installing. Is their any other perfect solution.

Answer (score 4):

#### [WinZip](http://www.winzip.com/) through [Wine](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/wine) [image: Install wine]

In case we do not have access to a Windows or OSX box where WinZip is installed and running we can also install WinZip through Wine where it is rated [Gold or Platinum](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=2). ZIPX is supported from version 12.1.

My own tests on Wine (Ubuntu 12.04) running WinZIP 15.5 and the most recent version 17.5 lets you compress, and extract ZIPX archives but of course Ubuntu **permissions will not be preserved** by doing so.

For some files (here tested with PNG images) we may still be able to extract them with the Ubuntu Archive Manager, but on most of the files extraction will fail.

In case we need to extract ZIPX files more than once we will have to buy the full version but just a single extraction (or compression) will work just fine when running the free 45 day evaluation version.

Answer (score 3):

Try to install 7z

```
sudo apt-get install p7zip-full
```

And then extract file using,

- Extracts all files from archive to the current directory.

  ```
  7z e archive.zipx
  ```
- If you want extract files with full paths,

  ```
  7z x archive.zipx
  ```

See more options: https://sevenzip.osdn.jp/chm/cmdline/commands/extract.htm

Comment: you may want to consider using the `x` flag instead `e` as it will preserve the directory structure from the zipx archive

Answer (score 1):

The Unarchiver's open-source command-line tools [are listed](https://github.com/ashang/unar#supported-unusual-formats) as supporting zipx, so one option is:

```
sudo apt-get install unar
```

Then, you unpack using:

```
unar FILENAME.zipx
```

(The Unarchiver is to MacOS as 7-Zip is to Windows, so they both support a *massive* swath of formats but there are also many formats where they *don't* overlap. For example, 7-Zip doesn't support Stuffit `.sit` and `.sitx` files and, because macOS supports them natively, The Unarchiver doesn't support `.dmg` files.)

Answer (score 0):

You can not. ZIPX is Windows 7 only at the moment.

> Since the ZIPX file format is rather newly introduced by WinZIP, there are few zip utilities supporting it (WinRAR doesn't support ZIPX yet, neither does 7Zip). **Thus, if you happen to encounter a corrupt zipx file you cannot repair it since no zipx repair utilities are yet available, so the only option is to go back and repackage the files (if you still have them) and only after that re-create the zipx archive.**

[Source](http://website.informer.com/visit?domain=zipxfile.com)